# Warning "[Parameters] Parameters : Invalid chunk ignored" when posting from a managed bean

Tags: java, jsf

I am opening a `HttpURLConnection` from within a managed bean to post to an external service.  When I make the call to `HttpUrlConnection.getInputStream()` I am getting the following warning:

> WARN [Parameters] Parameters : Invalid chunk ignored

Everything processes just fine, but I'd like to keep a bunch of those warnings out of our logs. What is causing this warning and how might I stop it from occurring?

Here is the relevant code:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyController {

  private void doStuff() {
    ...
    URL url = new URL(externalServiceUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(postData);
    wr.flush();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); // Warning logged after this line
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: So.. If you outcomment that line, then the warning doesn't appear anymore? That's odd, because I recognize this as one of the Tomcat/JBoss server builtin warnings whenever a request parameter is been submitted without a name, which in turn has completely nothing to do with `URLConnection#getInputStream()`.

Comment: It turns out that I was building my postData string with an "&" at the start.  Since the external service was actually just another war running in the same jboss instance, it was the post to the external service that was generating the warning.  Thanks for the comment that led me to my error!

Comment: Oh, you're HTTP-connecting to a service which runs on the same container and which logs to the same logfile? How awkward... :) Anyway, I'll repost the comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: Well, I'm just doing some proof-of-concept right now, so yes..It will all be separated eventually!

Comment: I see. That's perfectly reasonable :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This warning can occur whenever the query string contains an invalid chunk, such as a request parameter without a name:

```
name1=value1&=value2&name3=value3
```

or in your particular case, a `&` in the beginning (essentially, the first chunk is invalid):

```
&name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

As per the comments, you seem to be HTTP-connecting to a service which runs on the same container and logs to the same logfile. This warning is actually coming from the service container itself, not from `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: I saw this error with an extra ampersand in the query string (in this case before name1:  http://www.stackoverflow.com/blah?&name1=value1&name2=value2

Answer (score -1):

I removed this warning from my logs by adding:

```
<category name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters">
  <priority value="ERROR"/>
```

to my jboss-log4j.xml config file.
It was set to TRACE level before.